# What do I do when an answer solves my problem but doesn't answer my question?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, accepted-answer

So I asked [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307993/388916) about how to do `x` because I wanted to achieve `y`, then two answers were submitted that helped me achieve `y` but didn't address how to do `x`. My problem was solved, but my question wasn't answered. What should I do? It certainly won't help any future visitors if the accepted answer doesn't even address the issue in the question title.

Should I

- Wait for another answer?
- Edit the question title to "how to achieve `y`" instead of "how to do `x`"?
- Mark the question for deletion because it's stupid?

Or something else?

<sub>I obviously upvoted both answers</sub>

Comment: Generally, if the answer solved my problem in a non-trivial way (not simply defining it away somehow) I'll accept the answer, though with a comment.  I usually hold out a few days for a "real" answer first, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the time, we ask questions to solve a problem "y".  But frequently we don't know how to phrase, tag, or even conceive of the problem in the manner that subject experts are accustomed to.  This is one reason why it's so easy to edit and retag question.

But it's still solving the problem "y" that's most likely to be helpful, not the question "x" -- which may reflect a suboptimal way of looking at the problem.  So, **if an answer solves the problem, accept that answer.**

**If the question does not reflect the problem, edit the question!**

In [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14307993/331508), it seems like the question title does not match the question body anyway.  The title might more accurately be something like: "How to scroll the viewport by one line without leaving insert mode?".  Also, don't put tags in the title.

Comment: So I'm having a similar dilemma. My question reflected my problem. The answer solved my problem. But it didn't answer my question (which has applications far broader than my situation). This is the question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/130092/custom-controller-with-custom-object-multiple-record-display-object-field-with-c