# What do I do if an answer to a question solves my problem, but it isn't my question, and doesn't solve the problem posed in the question?

Tags: discussion, questions

This question is very similar to [What do I do when an answer solves my problem but doesn't answer my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163640/what-do-i-do-when-an-answer-solves-my-problem-but-doesnt-answer-my-question) but slightly different.

In this case, I've arrived to [How to set Ant properties based on variables in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660366/how-to-set-ant-properties-based-on-variables-in-eclipse) through a Google search. One of the answers solves my problem, but hasn't addressed the question that was initially raised.

Do I upvote the answer that helped me, even though it's already been pointed out that the answer wasn't helpful to the person asking? Is there something else I should do also/instead?

I don't currently have enough reputation to post a comment myself.

Comment: I've seen it done like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10004664/495455 - an upvote with a comment.

Comment: As I said above - I don't currently have enough reputation to post a comment.

Comment: [Well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119827/why-cant-i-comment), apart from writing a question here and upvoting on [so], doesn't look like you can do much.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do I do when an answer solves my problem but doesn't answer my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163640/what-do-i-do-when-an-answer-solves-my-problem-but-doesnt-answer-my-question)

Comment: Don't be afraid to edit information into your question as to why the answer you accepted actually solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks Austin, but not a duplicate - you'll see I actually cited that one as the similar one.  You see, in this case, the original question is _not_ mine!  Same goes, Lance - the question isn't mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If an answer helps you solve your question, You are perfectly justified in leaving an up-vote even if it doesn't necessarily address the OP's question.

One of the goals of answers on this site is for answers to help future visitors, which that one apparently did.  and up-vote is perfectly fine.

If you're feeling particularly generous and really want to reward the answerer, than you can also leave a bounty if you so choose, but most people are happy to receive what up-votes they get.